# How to share Workbenches in Salesforce Marketing Cloud Social Studio to all the users in Workspaces

Tags: marketing-cloud, social-studio

I have created a Workbenches and it isn't visible to other users.

Wondering how to share Workbenches in Salesforce Marketing Cloud Social Studio to all the users in the Workspaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be possible at the moment, didn't see any option for it.

Documentation also states it pretty straight that:

> When you create a workbench, only you can see the workbench, no other
>   Social Studio user can see your workbenches.

- [**Social Studio Workbenches**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ss_analyze_workbenches.htm&type=5)